# capturing specific or group in regex C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to parse match a file name like xxxxSystemCheckedOut.png where xxx can be any prefix to the file name and System and Checked out are keywords to identify.

EDIT: I wasn't being clear on all the possible file names and their results. So filenames can be

- ***xxxx*System.png** produces (group 1: xxxx group 2: System)
- ***xxxx*SystemCheckedOut.png** produces (group 1: xxxx group 2: System group 3: CheckedOut)
- ***xxxx*CheckedOut.png** produces (group 1: xxxx group 2: CheckedOut)

this is my current regex, it matchs the file name like I want it to but can't get it to group in the right way. 
Using the previous example I'd like the groups to be like this:

1. xxxx
2. System
3. CheckedOut
4. .png

`(?:([\w]*)(CheckedOut|System)+(\.[a-z]*)\Z)`

Comment: I'm using this website to test my regexs since its easier this way. www.regexhero.net

Comment: How many characters can your prefix be? You're illustrating that it's either 3 or 4?

Comment: @Shar1er80 no the prefix can be any length

Comment: And will the file extension always be at least 3 or more characters?

Comment: @Shar1er80 I'm always expecting it to be a png

Comment: What is this `(CheckedOut|System)+` ? This can match multiple times. This will produce an array from the capture collection. So, you mean something like `CheckedOutSystemSystemSystemCheckedOut.png` is ok?

Comment: If that's the case, then you don't really get any extra info based on the order I don't think. Might as well use `((?:CheckedOut|System)+)`

Comment: @sln that should not work, good catch I should recheck what I've ended up settling on

Comment: @sln it should only catch one or more time for each keyword

Comment: Actually, you over complicate this. You only need to find a keyword before the `.png`. What does it matter which one or how many or where? If it matched, you can check the contents of group 1 `.*(System|CheckedOut)\.png$` That is the validation, nothing else. Or you could analyze the capture collection  `.*?(System|CheckedOut)+\.png$`

Comment: @sln I actually need the groups separately so I know how to operate on the image, each keyword ends in different operations on the image

Comment: Like I said, either way, _Capture collection_ is involved. Might as well simply get everything you need in one keyword group `(.*?)(System|CheckedOut)+\.png$`, it gives you more precise information (and order). To have separate groups like this `(?:(System)|(CheckedOut))+` is ludicrous.

Comment: @sln I see, this is my first time using regexs is there a dip in performance?

Comment: (Not a performance issue) I mean, if you care about keyword order, there is a distinction between the two. Dot-Net uses _Capture Collections_ of groups and normal _groups_. In this case quantifying a group capture, overwrites the actual group each time, but the capture collection for the group builds up (adds to) an array each quantified match. If using a simple alternation of literals, the array order (match order) is maintained between keyword matches. Otherwise, with separate captures, the order is not maintained.

Comment: I'll post a C# example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]
Give this a try.

Pattern: `(.*?)(?:(System)|(CheckedOut)|(Cached))+(.png)\Z`

String: `xxxxTESTSystemCached.png`

Groups:

1. xxxxTest
2. System
3. Cached
4. .png

https://regex101.com/r/jE5eA4/1

Comment: yes because xxxxSystem.png and xxxxCheckedOut.png and xxxSystemCheckedOut.png are all valid. thats why i included the or

Comment: sorry I should have written my question more clearly

Comment: Take a look at my edit, I think it may work for you.

Comment: savior, thank you. Made me pull my hair out but sucks even more knowing I was close

Comment: I'm confused...  The pattern matched for "SystemCheckOut.png" I thought this was a bad match cause there is no prefix?

Comment: @Shar1er80 the main problem was getting multiple keywords to group on their own, this does that and I've fixed this answer so the  case you mentioned is corrected

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE - Based on comments to other answers:**
This should work for all combinations of System/CheckedOut/Cached:

```
(\w+?)(System)?(CheckedOut)?(Cached)?(.png)
```

https://regex101.com/r/qT2sX9/1

Note that that the groups for missing keywords will still exist, so for example:

"abcdSystemCached.png" gives:

Match 1 : "abcd"
Match 2 : "System"
Match 3 :
Match 4 : "Cached"
Match 5 : ".png"

And "1234CheckedOutCached.png" gives:

Match 1 : "abcd"
Match 2 :
Match 3 : "CheckedOut"
Match 4 : "Cached"
Match 5 : ".png"

This is kinda nice as you know a particular keyword will always be a certain position, so it becomes like a flag.

Comment: it was close but it breaks when xxxxCheckedOutxxx.png is also a case which should not match but does

Answer (score 1):

From the comments: `I actually need the groups separately so I know how to operate on the image, each keyword ends in different operations on the image`

You really don't need to use separate capture buffers on the keywords.
If you need the order of the matched keywords relative to one another,
you'd use the below code. Even if you didn't need the order it could be
done like that.

```
 ( .*? )                       # (1)
 ( System | CheckedOut )+      # (2)
 \.png $
```

C#:

```
string fname = "xxxxSystemCheckedOutSystemSystemCheckedOutCheckedOut.png";
Regex RxFname = new Regex( @"(.*?)(System|CheckedOut)+\.png$" );

Match fnameMatch = RxFname.Match( fname );
if ( fnameMatch.Success )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group 0 = {0}", fnameMatch.Groups[0].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Group 1 = {0}", fnameMatch.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Last Group 2 = {0}\n", fnameMatch.Groups[2].Value);

    CaptureCollection cc = fnameMatch.Groups[2].Captures;

    Console.WriteLine("Array and order of group 2 matches (collection):\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < cc.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] = '{1}'", i, cc[i].Value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Group 0 = xxxxSystemCheckedOutSystemSystemCheckedOutCheckedOut.png
Group 1 = xxxx
Last Group 2 = CheckedOut

Array and order of group 2 matches (collection):

[0] = 'System'
[1] = 'CheckedOut'
[2] = 'System'
[3] = 'System'
[4] = 'CheckedOut'
[5] = 'CheckedOut'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Regex wizard, so if this can be shortened/tidied I'd love to know, but this groups like you want based on the keywords you gave:

**Edited based on OPs clarification of the file structure**

```
(\w+?)(system)?(checkedout)?(cached)?(.png)/ig
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sM2iT1/2)

Edit: beercohol and jon have me beat ;-)

Comment: This works, but make sure you use the start/stop characters as well to ensure the entire string matches: `^(\S+)\s*(system)(checkedout|cached)(\S+)\s*$`, and pass this as the options: `RegExOptions.IgnoreCase`.  I don't think a global option is required when looking at a single line string-- I'd expect it to not match if a newline was found.

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for :( the system is not constant, it should also work for file names like xxxCheckedOutCached.png and have checkedout and cached in seperate groups

Comment: I'm confused about which order these keywords can appear in. So the file name always begins with a random string, then the word System may or may not appear at all, then there's one or both keywords of CheckedOut and Cached, then the extension. Is this right?

Comment: not exactly, there will be some prefix xxxx and then any number of keywords System/Chached/CheckedOut will appear and it needs group those accordingly. So xxxxCheckedOut.png should group to xxxx and checkedout and .png or xxxxCachedSystem.png and should group xxx cached and system.

Comment: OK, so there'll be a random string, then a combination of ANY of the 3 key words in any order, then the file extension. And then you want to group based on random string, separate key words, file extension. Right?

Comment: yes but not all 3 have to present, one being there is just as valid of a case

Comment: I think the reason that you're getting crappy answers is that the filename structure isn't 100% clear in your question. If you update your question with some more clarity around the file structure you're more likely to get an answer. I'll see about updating mine later if someone hasn't beaten me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere (can't remember where) the more precise your pattern is, the better performance you'll get from it.

So try this pattern

```
"(\\w+?)(?:(System)|(CheckedOut))+(.png)"
```

Code Sample:

```
List<string> fileNames = new List<string>
{
    "xxxxSystemCheckedOut.png",         // Good
    "SystemCheckedOut.png",             // Good
    "1afweiljSystemCheckedOutdgf.png",  // Bad - Garbage characters before .png
    "asdf.png",                         // Bad - No System or CheckedOut
    "xxxxxxxSystemCheckedOut.bmp",      // Bad - Wrong file extension
    "xxSystem.png",                     // Good
    "xCheckedOut.png"                   // Good
};

foreach (Match match in fileNames.Select(fileName => Regex.Match(fileName, "(\\w+?)(?:(System)|(CheckedOut))+(.png)")))
{
    List<Group> matchedGroups = match.Groups.Cast<Group>().Where(group => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(group.Value)).ToList();
    if (matchedGroups.Count > 0)
    {
        matchedGroups.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Results:

```
xxxxSystemCheckedOut.png
xxxx
System
CheckedOut
.png

SystemCheckedOut.png
System
CheckedOut
.png

xxSystem.png
xx
System
.png

xCheckedOut.png
x
CheckedOut
.png
```

Comment: only problem is that xxxxxxCheckedOut.png and xxxxxSystem.png is also a valid case along with the ones you posted.